# How do I set the projection and coordinate system for a TIFF file?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a [topographic](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211495/hill300m.zip) map of California (obtained from [CAL-Atlas](http://www.atlas.ca.gov/download.html#/casil/imageryBaseMapsLandCover/baseMaps/hillshades/0030m_ned)) as a TIFF file. I tried importing it into QGis, but it displays the map using a pixel-based coordinate system rather than latitude/longitude (the `.prj` file indicates that it uses NAD83 Albers projection).

How can I rectify the coordinate system for this raster file in QGis? I'm using QGis 1.8 for this project, but also have 2.0 if necessary.

What if I am using QGis >=2.7v what should I do for the same..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of the TIFF file is correct, don't try to change that.

What you may want is to change the projection of the **project**. You can do that with `Settings -> Project Settings` in QGIS 1.8. In the CRS tab, you can change the project CRS to EPSG:4269, which is NAD83 in degrees.

And make sure you have `On-the-fly-reprojection`enabled.